# Build Deployment basics

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, deployment, build

I am more into UI dev and less into Java...So, I would like to understand what exactly does the following things mean;
1. Build Deploy (Is it just a folder coped to a server and if yes, are there only class files in there,...)
2. What does exploded build mean?

If someone could explain me in very easy language (and not extremely technical), that would be really great...

Also any online resources in simple language would be helpful..

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Build Deploy

   You build your application into some packaging and deploy it on the server.

for example if its web app you pack it in war file and put this war file on the server webapp for tomcat (dir differs from server to server) and start the server to deploy it.

Comment: Thx for that..So finally you put only 1 compressed file on the server and then restart it (which will kind of unarchive it) ? Is that true?...Also what about exploded build ?

Comment: 1. for tomcat please refer [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/deployer-howto.html) , about *build exploded* you need to provide more information, heard this thing first time

Comment: "exploded" term is there even on the URL you gave.."exploded web application"

Comment: ah... it is extracted form of war..you might have observed this thing in other like php, asp ,, where they just copy pages ..etc in to a dir, something like this

Comment: So how does it work..like you first create a .war file locally, copy to server and then extract (or explode) it there. Is that how it works?

Comment: yes we build war first. then we either copy it to server , or we upload it from server's interface to deploy , for later case it will deploy app. for first case you will have to restart the server, so that server will look into its webapp dir for deployment descriptor and will deploy that app

Comment: hey.Do you have any other useful resource online..i mean the one you provided on tomcat seems a bit too technical..do you know a place where these things are explained in a very easy-to-understand language..Plus something related to WinSCP...

Comment: Like I do not understand when you say " upload it from server's interface to deploy .."

Comment: well there are some server, tomcat,glassfish they provide a web interface to upload that war packaging to deploy

Comment: Ok..So does the WAR files only contain .class files or even the source .java .jsp files

Comment: depends on your app packaging process. generally it contains classes of servlet and others..other libraries, jsp. images, css , js etc..

Answer (score 1):

1. Build Deploy

Build deploy process will include many things such as

a) Checking the server configurations like database configurations, server resources configurations etc.

b) Checking the Application Configurations , means any changes in the application related configuration files.

c) Deplying the code on to the server
during this process server will read up the deployment descritor and deploy the application based on the configuration provided in DD xml (web.xml)
Also it deploy the ejb modules based on the configuration provided in ejb-jar.xml